# pass multiple parameters to a javascript and update html content bases on both parameters + php loop

Tags: php, javascript, parameters, return

I have form that uses jquery to fetch mysql data with an external php page.

the script is essentially an autocomplete for an input field. trouble is that I have the input field in a loop, field ID is being determine by the counter '$i' in the loop.

as such I want to pass the user entered value of the input box to the javascript along with the counter value '$i' so that the javascript can return the result to the correct input box in the loop.

I hope that makes sense.

the original and working code for a single input box is below:

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("autocompleteperson.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
</div>
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
    <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 20px;" alt="upArrow" />
    <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

So what I want to do is pass the row number ($i)  to the javascript as well so that it returns the value to the correct input box. My basic attempts at this are below [apologies for my lack of javascript skill :-) ]

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(rownumber, inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("autocompleteperson.php", {queryString: ""+(inputString+rownumber)+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputString'+'rownumber').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
```

**PHP / HTML**

```
<table>
<?  for ( $i = 1; $i <=50; $i++ ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString<? echo  $i; ?>" onkeyup="lookup(<? echo  $i; ?>,this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                        <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 20px;" alt="upArrow" />
                        <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </td>
            </tr>
        <? } ?>
</table>
```

The second part of the question would be getting the div suggestionbox to appear in the correct place as well. The same applies where I would like the name of the suggestionbox to append the row number '$i'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards,

**UPDATED CODE**

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("autocompleteperson.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup

function fill(rownumber, thisValue) { // add the rownumber as a parameter
        $('#inputString'+rownumber).val(thisValue); // remove the quotation marks
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<table>
<?
    for ( $i = 1; $i <=50; $i++ ) { 
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td> Job <? echo  $i; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <SELECT NAME=job<? echo $i; ?> id=job<? echo $i; ?> style="width:150px;border: 1px solid #2608c3;color:red"> 
                    <OPTION VALUE=0 ></option>
                    <option>
                    <?=$optionjobs?> 
                    </option>
                    </SELECT>
                </td>
                <td> Person </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString<? echo  $i; ?>" onkeyup="lookup(<? echo  $i; ?>,this.value);" onblur="fill(<? echo  $i; ?>,this.value);" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                        <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 20px;" alt="upArrow" />
                        <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?
            }
        ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, in the basic code that works, you're calling `fill()` without giving any parameters whereas in the javascript, you're waiting for `thisValue`.

Now for your problem, let's take your `fill` function and do some modifications

```
    function fill(rownumber, thisValue) { // add the rownumber as a parameter
        $('#inputString'+rownumber).val(thisValue); // remove the quotation marks
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
```

and in the HTML file

```
[...]
<div>
<input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString<? echo  $i; ?>" onkeyup="lookup(<? echo  $i; ?>,this.value);" onblur="fill(<? echo  $i; ?>,this.value);" />
[...]
```

simply add in the `fill()` function the needed parameters.

Comment: Thanks leMoisela, much appreciated. tried making he changes but not working. I beleive the function, lookup is not getting the correct parameters or being called. any more help will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: try using `console.log()` in order to print in the logs the different parameters. You'll see what are they values and this is where the problem leads. (in recent browsers, you're also able to see the log). That said, do you get any error displayed???

Comment: Hi, No errors from the browser, not sure on how to use conolse.log but will read up on it. I have updated the question to have my current code as per your advice. you can also see an example at: http://www.shedatabase.co.za/versionfour/configuredepartment.php?departmentid=11
Thanks again for the help. much appreciated.

Comment: nothing is appearing in google chrome console, not 100% sure I am using it correctly though. Thanks leMoisela.

Comment: when you say nothing is appearing, you mean nothing wrong, or really nothing ?? if you add in your js script `console.log(rownumber);` within your fill() function, what do you get?? You should have printed in your console the rownumber each time you trigger that function

Comment: Hi leMoisela, ok progress. it is now displaying the div popup. but when selecting a value it is not populating (any) input field. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: did you get some new improvements? that may be a bad guess, but what if on the line `$('#inputString'+rownumber).val(thisValue);` you add `+''` after `rownumber` ?? BTW, could you explain me what `this.value` is in the HTML file? (print it with `console.log`) It seems to me that it has no value, or 50 times the same value, which would not be what your expect.

Comment: Thanks for the continued assistance. changes do not solve the issue unfortunately. I was under the impression that this passed the value from the input box t the function as a parameter? is it okay to put the entire function in the loop as well? Thanks again?

Comment: yeah, well remove my last guess than :) concerning the `this.value`, could you do a `console.log(this.value)` within the for loop just to check what your values are/is. Depending on that I think we can go forward !

Comment: Thansk agin for the help, console.log inside the loop doesnt generate anything new. only the log for the javsdcript is appearing.

Comment: you mean that `console.log(this.value)` prints nothing? Well in that case it is absolutely normal that it is not populating any field. Instead of `this.value`, put, for each value in your loop, the value you want to be printed in your div popup (recall that the second parameter from your `fill($a,$b)` function is the value you're going to print, so it has to have the value you want)

Comment: Thanks @leMoisela, appreciate the explanation. can you assist with some code as I am not 100% sure on how to do this? Thanks again,

Comment: well, since I don't know what you want to print, lets try with a simple test. change in your html code `fill(<? echo  $i; ?>,<? echo  $i; ?>);` --> if everything works fine, numbers from 1 to 50 should be printed in every field. (number 1 in field 1, number 2 in field 2, etc)